# Check if MySQL is running in a Windows batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have a simple batch file to spin up a dev site in XAMPP.  However, if I have forgotten to start MySQL, it fails to handle the parts of the process that set up a database for the site.

In a Windows batch file, is there a way to check if MySQL is running, and if not, start it?

I don't have any examples that I have tried because I simply have not been able to find any.

Comment: `sc queryex MySQL`? I don't use Windows, so this is just a guess based on documentation. Also I am not sure what the service name is for the version you are running. `sc` can also be used to start or stop a service.

Comment: I would assume `%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe Query ...`, `QueryEx` may not be necessary. Open a Command Prompt window, type `%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out how it works.